# Converting from Polar form to Cartesian Form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am just starting with complex numbers and vectors. The question is:

> Convert the following to Cartesian form.
>
> a) $8 \,\text{cis} \frac \pi4$

The formula given is:

$$z = x +yi = r\space(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$$

With $r=8$ and $\theta = \frac\pi4$, I did:

$$z=8\left(\cos\frac\pi4 + i \sin \frac\pi4\right)$$
$$z = 8(0.71 + i0.71)$&
$$z = 5.66 + i5.66$$

The answer they give in the answers section is:

$$z=4\sqrt2(1+i)$$

I know this is the same answer just written approximately. Is someone able to take me through how you get to $z=4\sqrt2(1+i)$ instead of $z = 5.66 + i5.66$?

Comment: $\cos\dfrac\pi4=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

Comment: `I know this is the same answer just written differently` No, because $\,4 \sqrt{2} \ne 5.66\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. Should have written approximately.

Comment: Also, while everyone is here, does anyone know why when I write fractions in Mathsjax they come out so small? And everyone elses are normal size. I am new to stack exchange and mathsjax

Comment: @JuanPablo That was the point. When an exact result is readily available, just an approximation won't cut it. P.S. About fractions, try `$$\frac{a}{b}$$` or `$\dfrac{a}{b}$` or `$\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}$`. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more MathJax tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the $\pi\over4$ family:

$$\cos \dfrac{\pi}{4} = \sin \dfrac{\pi}{4} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Then applying this result to $8\,\text{cis} \frac{\pi}{4}$:

$$z=8\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} + i\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right) = 8\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1+i)$$

And then multiply:

$$8\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} = \dfrac{8\sqrt 2}{2}=4\sqrt2$$

$$8\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1+i) = 4\sqrt 2(1+i)$$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I was stuck at the very first bit. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JuanPablo You've got to remember your unit circle :)